# How to unit test Request.Form[""]?

Tags: c#, forms, unit-testing, request, moq

Below is my controller's method :-

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Search(SearchViewModel model)
   {
       string selection = Request.Form["Options"];
       if (selection == "str1")
       {
           -----------------------------
       }        
   }
```

And it's based on the condition where its getting value from Request.Form.But Request.Form is only provide Get property and i can't set it's value on unit testing method.Is there any way to set it's value ?

Answer (score 4):

None of the above methods work for me. I end up using the following without Mock.

```
DefaultHttpContext httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
httpContext.Request.Scheme = "http";
httpContext.Request.Host = new HostString("localhost");
var formCol = new FormCollection(new Dictionary<string, 
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues>
{   
            { "key1", "value1" },
            { "key2", "value2" }
}); 
httpContext.Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpContext.Request.Form = formCol;
var context = new MyContext();
var controller = new MyController(context);
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext {
            HttpContext = httpContext
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not use Request.Form["Options"] inside. You can have Option property inside your SearchViewModel class and can use it instead.
For scenario where you are required to use session in the controller method you can  use ModelBinder

Answer (score 3):

We can mock and Unit Test Request.Form objects by using moq. Please refer below code

```
var controllercontext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
        controllercontext.Setup(frm => frm.HttpContext.Request.Form.Set("Options", "1"));

Yourcontroller.ControllerContext = controllercontext.Object;
var response = YourController.Search(new SearchViewModel() {//Your Model Data..}) as ActionResult;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working way to mock the form collection
Note, that I have done the Request.Form instantiation with the help of the above code of maruthi. Assigning form fields, however, didn't work with his code, so you'll need to return it from the setup.

```
 NameValueCollection form = new NameValueCollection();
 form["Key"] = "Value";    
 var controllercontext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
 controllercontext.Setup(frm => frm.HttpContext.Request.Form).Returns(form);
 _controller.ControllerContext = controllercontext.Object;
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean the value of Request.Form["Options"] ? if so you should know that this is an HttpRequest, and what you need to do is to mock it from the http request and not from within your code because you can't just alter it here.

Comment: Can you describe any example of mock it ?

Comment: I don't have an example to mock an http request .. but I am talking about the idea it self. A quick search show this question on stackoverflow .. check it out and start from there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732870/mocking-httprequest-and-httpresponse-for-mvc-application